# Method sends unvalidated data to browser

Tags: javascript

I am getting XSS vulnerability on using location.hash in my code.

location.hash='val/' + id;

When I scan through fortify, it is pointing out this as critical issue. Also, I am using location.hash at several places, but fortify is not reporting it.

Can anyone help on this how to fix the issue?

Comment: This is a issue because the value of id is not validated/escaped, not the use of location.hash. Please refer to this article https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation

Comment: How do you obtain `id`, here and in other places? (In particular, do you check it for characters it contains etc.?)

Comment: I get id from session storage of a browser. I have give not null check for it. Wouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: In other places, I am getting Id from AJAX response.